# Git diff between {HEAD, staged, working dir}

Tags: git

I have a file which I have changed to add 2 new features to the systems. Now I only want to commit one of the features on the branch. So I went through the changes with git add -p and now I want to verify that I only got the parts of this one feature and that I didn't forget any. Therefore my idea was to look at the differences as diff between {HEAD, staged, working dir}.

I tried to get the right handles for the different files and then combine it with a git difftool call.

HEAD: `git show HEAD:src/autosub.py`   --> `HEAD:src/autosub.py`

staged: `git show :src/autosub.py`     --> `:src/autosub.py`

working dir: `src/autosub.py`

But the combined call does not work: `git difftool HEAD:src/autosub.py :src/autosub.py src/autosub.py`

What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not using Git (or really any VCS) the way it was intended to be used.  The smarter things to do here would have been to make separate commits for each feature, possibly in a feature branch or even two branches.  Had you done that, it would have been relatively easy to bring in whichever of the two features you wanted.

Comment: I am aware that I messed up, therefore I am trying to fix it now... I thought I would bring the 2 features in together as one, but now I realized they are rather 2 features and the 2nd one should not be brought in yet.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen separate commits for each feature is precisely what OP is trying to do, and the question is: how to verify what changes have been staged and what changes have not been staged. I don't see that as a workflow problem.

Comment: @1615903 Your comment assumes that the OP neatly divided the features between the stage and working directory.  This wasn't evident to me and, if true, I think should have been stated.

Comment: _"I went through the changes with git add -p and now I want to verify that I only got the parts of this one feature and that I didn't forget any"_ - I think this makes it clear that OP did exactly that.

Comment: `git difftool` simply doesn't do that. You need a different command, such as `diff3` (see zigam's answer).

Answer (score 4):

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> `git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...​]`

It only accepts commit as arguments and is not really intended to do a diff3 with other things than commit.
You have to do it in 2 parts:

- To get the diff between your working directory and the stage : `git diff[tool]`
- To get the diff between the stage and `HEAD` : `git diff[tool] --staged` (or `git diff --cached`)

The second one is the way to see what you will commit.

You can configure [`diff.mnemonicPrefix`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-diffmnemonicPrefix) to see the `w` (working dir), `i` (index/stage), or `c` (commit/HEAD) prefix in the diff instead of `a` and `b`.

If you really need to do a diff3 between WD/stage/HEAD:

```
git show HEAD:path > /tmp/head
git show :path > /tmp/staged
diff3 /tmp/head /tmp/staged path
rm /tmp/head /tmp/staged
```

You can put this in a shell function or a script then add it as an [alias](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias):

```
# Diff-3 between _C_ommit/_I_ndex/_W_orkingdir
git config --global alias.diff3ciw '! the_script'
```

Comment: This gives me 2 views: {working dir, staged} and {stage, HEAD} but I would like one view {HEAD, staged, working dir}

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot directly with git.